# pandas how to import csv with chinese characters

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv (r'path/filename.csv',encoding= 'gbk')  
print (df)
```

Out:

```
error:UnicodeDecodeError: 'gbk' codec can't decode byte 0xad in position 12: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Comment: Googling '0xad' says that its a type of hyphen character. if pandas can't handle it then you may need to find another way to do some sort of cleaning of the file pre-pandas. Alternatively, im not sure about encoding options for Chinese but with some trial and error you may be able to find something that works for you

Comment: try this ?`df = pd.read_csv(path, engine='python', encoding='utf-8-sig')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8')`

If it's not working, then try the following:

`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='ISO-8859-1')`

And after using this, ig you get 'ParserError' then use this:

`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding='utf-8', engine='python')`

If not, then use the following:

`import pandas as pd`

`import chardet`

`with open('filename.csv', 'rb') as f:`
`result = chardet.detect(f.read())`

`df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', encoding=result['encoding'])`

I hope one of the things works out for you. Cheers!